# Count number of plots generated from a function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot

I am looking for a way to find the number of generated plots from a function in R. Here is a dummy code for elaboration:

```
 ploting = function(x)
   {
   for(i in 1:x){
     print(plot(rnorm(10)))
   }
 }
```

How can I manage to obtain the number of generated plots from this function? (which is equal to x in this case assuming x is a positive integer).

P.s: I'm using ggplot2 for my actual function if that is of any importance.

Comment: If you specify the range yourself in the loop, why is it necessary to repeat the same later? You can save them in a list and get the length of that list?

Comment: As mentioned it's a dummy function. The actual function generates plos based on the data and arguments, so the number of plots differs each time the function is used. So a way to determain number of plots when using the function is of interest.

Comment: use lapply - one plot for each subelement, and then `length(your_list)`. Or, as suggested above, the number of iteration should be clear beforehand from your loop. So you could store this number separately and also return this together with the plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could plot to a PDF device:

```
pdf("E:/temp/test.pdf")
ploting(3)
dev.off()
```

The number of pages in the PDF is the number of plots and the plots are archived as an additional benefit.

You could also trace `plot` (or/and any functions used for plotting in your function):

```
trace(plot, quote(nplot <<- nplot + 1))
nplot <- 0

ploting(3)

nplot
#[1] 3
untrace(plot)
```

Preferably, you would just modify `ploting` to return or `message` the number of plots.

Comment: The first approach is very smart! But not very memory efficient probably. The second one I'm needs adjustments to the function which is not optimal for me, I wonder if it can be done without changing the function?

Comment: 1. Is hard drive space an issue to you? 2. The second approach does not modify any function.

Comment: 1. Not hard drive memory! generating 100 plots outof milions of data ponts and creating excels would take a lot of time though!  2. I am using ggplot as mentioned in the post in my actual function, and this approach does not work with that. I still get nplot=0.

Comment: 1. I don't understand what "creating excels" means. Generating 100 scatter plots with millions of data points will take a lot of time, yes. But this is true for any plotting device, regardless if it is a file device or the default screen device. 2. Then trace `print.ggplot`.